# SHAP: exporting shap values from KernelExplainer to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, shap

I am working on a binary classification and using `kernelExplainer` to explain the results of my model (logistic regression).

My code is as follows

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
lr = LogisticRegression() # fit and predict statements not shown
masker = Independent(X_train, max_samples=100)
explainer = KernelExplainer(lr.predict,X_train)
bv = explainer.expected_value
sv = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

sdf_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id': X_train.index.values.repeat(X_train.shape[1]),
    'feature': X_train.columns.to_list() * X_train.shape[0],
    'feature_value': X_train.values.flatten(),
    'base_value': bv,
    'shap_values': sv.values[:,:,1].flatten()  #error here I guess
})
```

But I got the below error first. So, I updated the last line to `'shap_values': pd.DataFrame(sv).values[:,1].flatten()` but I got the second error shown below

> numpy.ndarray has no attribute values
>
> ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

wrt to datatypes, my `X_train` is a dataframe and `sv` is `numpy.ndarray`

I expect my output to be like as below (ignore the changes in base value. It should be constant). But the output structure is like below

[image]

Comment: not tested, but you can try `sv[:,:,1].flatten()` or `sv.flatten()` ?

Comment: If I try `sv[:,:,1].flatten()`, I get the below error - `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed`

Comment: ya, so try `sv[:,1]` or `sv[1,:]`

Comment: or `sv.flatten()`

Comment: yes, it worked. you wish to write as an answer?

Comment: Honestly I have no data, so cannot test, what working? `sv[:,1].flatten()`, `sv[:,1]`, `sv[1,:]`, `sv[1,:].flatten()` or `sv.flatten()` ?

Comment: Meaning, `sv.flatten() works` but I get error - `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 when I try `sv[1,:]` and when I try `sv[:,1]` , I get another error `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: what is `print (sv.shape)` and `print (len(bv))` ?

Comment: `sv.shape is (1,7)` and len(bv) throws error as object of type float has no len. It is just a float value and the value is `0.64`

Comment: So there is 8 rows and need assign 7 values?

Comment: There are 7 columns in my input data and 1 bv (constant) created through code above... Now, in my output, I would like to transform them into 5 columns. For each `row_id`, there will be 7 rows..(bv will be a seperate column).and we need to assign values

Comment: bv will be constant throughout for all row ids (and all rows).

Comment: hmm, so what is `print (len(X_train.values.flatten()))` ? It is `8` ?

Comment: I see that It is `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from shap import KernelExplainer
from shap import sample

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
lr = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000).fit(X_train, y_train)
background = sample(X_train, 100)
explainer = KernelExplainer(lr.predict, background)
sv = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
bv = explainer.expected_value
```

Note the shape of sv:

```
sv.shape
```

---

```
(398, 30)
```

which means:

```
sdf_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id': X_train.index.values.repeat(X_train.shape[1]),
    'feature': X_train.columns.to_list() * X_train.shape[0],
    'feature_value': X_train.values.flatten(),
    'base_value': bv,
    'shap_values': sv.flatten()  #error here I guess
})
sdf_train
```

---

```
    row_id  feature feature_value   base_value  shap_values
0   149 mean radius 13.74000    0.67    0.000000
1   149 mean texture    17.91000    0.67    -0.014988
2   149 mean perimeter  88.12000    0.67    0.060759
3   149 mean area   585.00000   0.67    0.028677
```

Comment: great. So,now oernelexplainer uses only 100 datapoints sample to learn the background? So, it will be faster.. Will accept it soon...

Comment: Any idea why previous answers worked with sv.values[:,:,1] and not with this?

Comment: From the top of my head, there 2 interfaces to SHAP: the old one, where shap values are numpy array which doesn't have `values` attribute. And new one, returning object of type `Explainer` (I believe). This one does have `.values` attribute. The new one is [almost] supposed to be fed to new plots like waterfall. But sometimes this doesn't work due to dimension incompatibility. This is why sometimes you need to unwind it and build again from scratch, like in case with RF.

Comment: As you're cycling through same errors time and again I do suggest the following: try new interface with `LinearExplainer` and `LogisticRegression` e.g. , which are supposed to work out of box. Check the type and dimentions of the resulting Explainer object. See how it fits waterfall expectations "as is". In case you get an error try to reconstruct Explainer object manually